# Converting jQuery Code to detect clicks on links with a specific class to Native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

ok so I can achieve what I am looking to do using jQuery very easily using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
  $('.pnTrig').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href').split("_").pop(); // get last character of string
    console.log(id); // check correct character is returned
    P7_TP3ctrl('p7TP3_1',id); // controls to show accordian panels    

  });
// ]]>
</script>
```

What I would like is for someone to show me how to convert this jQuery code to native JavaScript please.

Comment: What have you tried? There are a number of sites out there documenting how to convert jQuery to its equivalent plain old JavaScript...

Comment: this is where I got to but it gives me a console error (index):189 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null:
document.getElementById("#p7TP3c1_1").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /*e.preventDefault();
    console.log('link clicked');*/
    P7_TP3ctrl('p7TP3_1',1);return false;
});

Comment: Don't use `#` when calling `getElementById`.

Comment: Why are you calling `getElementById`? The jQuery code loooks for a class, not an ID, so you should be using `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: `$('selector')` can generally be replaced with `document.querySelectorAll('selector')`. But this returns a collection, so you need to loop over the results. You already seem to know that you can use `addEventListener` to replace `on`.

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I am not finding this process very intuitive at all and google gives me lots of pseudo code but no real world examples which is why I am struggling

Comment: What do you expect us to provide other than general explanations and pseudo-code? The only thing left would be to do it for you.

Comment: @Barmar it is not so much that I want you to do it for me but to teach me how it should be done so that I can understand the process and then expand on it, I had not found anything like Rob's answer while googling for a solution on how to approach this.

Comment: Did you look at the site I mentioned? It lists dozens of jQuery functions and shows the JS equivalent.

Comment: Yes I already had it bookmarked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a documented vanilla Javascript version.

```js
function clickHandler(event) {
  // execute preventDefault() if don't want the link to be followed (default browser behavior)
  event.preventDefault();

  // get the event target (what `this` would refer to in jQuery) 
  var target = event.target;
  // same as before
  var id = target.href.split('_').pop();
  // same as before
  P7_TP3ctrl('P7_TP3', id);
}

// get all elements with `pnTrig` class
var triggers = document.querySelectorAll('.pnTrig');

// apply the event handler to all matching elements
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
  // attach the event handler (don't define the event handling function here)
  triggers[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
}

function P7_TP3ctrl(label, id) {
  console.log("Clicked id: ", id);
}
```

```html
<a href="/foo/some_id_1" class="pnTrig">Link One</a>
<a href="/foo/some_id_2" class="pnTrig">Link Two</a>
```

Comment: that is fantastic thank you, if I may a question to clarify things in my own mind:

What purpose does false have in this statement:
triggers[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);

Comment: No problem! It is the `useCapture` argument, which MDN will explain better than me: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener